# What is the difference between 時々and たまに？

Tags: word-choice

I have been chatting online and both terms seem to mean the same thing. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

時々 means *sometimes* while たまに means *rarely*. たまに should not be confused with たまたま which means *by coincidence* (even if rarely たまたま can be used to say *sometimes/rarely*)

Comment: rarely ってどっちかっていうともう少し頻度の低い「めったに～ない」とかじゃないですかね・・「たまに」はrarely よりもう少し頻度の高い occasionally とかonce in a whileじゃないですかね・・「たまに～する」「ときどき～する」ってほとんど同じような・・

Comment: @Shoko To me めったに～ない is more *hardly ever* than *rarely*. I would say that ときどき～する is more frequent than たまに～する. But as you said *once in a while* may be a better gloss than *rarely* for たまに～する.